# Flask WTForms - Custom validators based of multiple form fields

Tags: python, forms, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I have a books table where quantity of books is available and I have borrows table where I enter the borrowed books and quantities.

I am trying to create custom validator function for my form that will show error message in form if quantity entered for borrow book is higher than available quantity in book table.

this is the model:

```
class Borrow(db.Model):
    """
    Create a Books table
    """

    __tablename__ = 'borrows'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True)
    quantity_borrow = db.Column(db.Integer)
    date_borrow = db.Column(db.DATE)
    employees_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('employees.id'))
    book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('books.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Borrow: {}>'.format(self.name)


class Book(db.Model):
    """
    Create a Books table
    """

    __tablename__ = 'books'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    book_name = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True,unique=True)
    author = db.Column(db.String(200), index=True)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer)
    department_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('departments.id'))
    employees_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('employees.id'))
    publisher = db.Column(db.String(200))
    no_of_pgs = db.Column(db.Integer)
    pbs_year = db.Column(db.Integer)
    genre_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('genres.id'), nullable=False)
    read = db.Column(db.Enum('NO', 'YES'), default='NO')

    borrows = db.relationship('Borrow', backref='book',
                                lazy='dynamic')
```

This is the view:

```
    @admin_role.route('/books/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @login_required
    def add_book():
        """
        Add a book to the database
        """
        check_admin_role()

        add_book = True

        form = BookForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            book = Book(book_name=form.book_name.data,
                        author=form.author.data,
                        quantity=form.quantity.data,
                        department_id=form.department_name.data,
                        employees_id=current_user.id,
                        publisher=form.publisher.data,
                        no_of_pgs=form.no_of_pgs.data,
                        pbs_year=form.pbs_year.data,
                        genre_id=form.genre_name.data,
                        read=form.read.data)
            try:
                # add department to the database
                db.session.add(book)
                db.session.commit()
                flash('You have successfully added a new department.')
            except:
                # in case department name already exists
                flash('Error: Book name already exists.')

            # redirect to departments page
            return redirect(url_for('admin_role.list_books'))

        # load department template
        return render_template('books/book.html', action="Add",
                               add_book=add_book, form=form,
                               title="Add Book", page="books")


    @admin_role.route('/borrows/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @login_required
    def add_borrow():
        """
        Add a borrow to the database
        """
        check_admin_role()

        add_borrow = True

        form = BorrowForm()

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            borrow = Borrow(name=form.name.data,
                        book_id=form.book_name.data,
                        quantity_borrow=form.quantity_borrow.data,
                        date_borrow=form.date_borrow.data)

            # add department to the database
            db.session.add(borrow)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('You have successfully added a new borrow.')


            # redirect to borrows page
            return redirect(url_for('admin_role.list_borrows'))

        # load department template
        return render_template('borrows/borrow.html', action="Add",
                               add_borrow=add_borrow, form=form,
                               title="Add Borrow", page="borrows")
```

And this is the form

```
class BookForm(FlaskForm):
    """
    Form for admin_role to add or edit a books
    """
    book_name = StringField('Book Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    author = StringField('Author', validators=[DataRequired()])
    genre_name = SelectField(coerce=int, validators=[DataRequired()])
    quantity = IntegerField('Quantity', validators=[DataRequired()])
    department_name = SelectField(coerce=int, validators=[DataRequired()])
    publisher = StringField('Publisher', validators=[DataRequired()])
    no_of_pgs = IntegerField('Number of pages', validators=[DataRequired()])
    pbs_year = IntegerField('Publishing Year', validators=[DataRequired()])
    read = SelectField("Read", choices=[(e, e) for e in Book.read.property.columns[0].type.enums])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    def __init__(self):
        super(BookForm, self).__init__()
        self.department_name.choices = [(c.id, c.name) for c in Department.query.all()]
        self.genre_name.choices = [(g.id, g.name) for g in Genre.query.all()]


class BorrowForm(FlaskForm):
    """
    Form for admin_role to add or edit a books
    """
    name = StringField('Borrower Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    book_name = SelectField(coerce=int, validators=[DataRequired()])
    quantity_borrow = IntegerField('Quantity Borrow', validators=[DataRequired())
    date_borrow = DateField('Borrow Date', validators=[DataRequired()])

    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    def __init__(self):
        super(BorrowForm, self).__init__()
        self.book_name.choices = [(c.id, c.book_name) for c in Book.query.all()]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wtforms you can validate a field by writing a method under that form class.

In this method, `validate_` prefix calls the field named after. `self` argument will be the `BorrowForm` class itself and the `field` argument will be the field you called with `validate_`

```
class BorrowForm(FlaskForm):
    ...

    def validate_quantity_borrow(self, field):
        if field.data > (Book.query.filter_by(id=self.book_name.data).first().quantity - sum(i.quantity_borrow for i in Borrow.query.filter_by(book_id=self.book_name.data).all()):
            raise ValidationError("More than we have")
```

`field` here is the `quantity_borrow` attribute of your `BorrowForm`. When submitted you need to get its data so `field.data` gives you entered quantity. After that you will get the book chosen by filtering the database with `book_id` as `self.book_name.data` which gives you, `self` as the `BorrowForm` class itself and `book_name` attribute of it then, the `data` of that attribute which is the id of book chosen.

You need to import your database models ,lets say in your forms.py file, and also you need to import `ValidationError`:

```
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError
```

Comment: This will provide me total number of books but what i need is to check against the number of available books. This means that if `field.data > Book.query.filter_by(id=self.book_name.data).first().quantity - sum of all quantity_borrow in Borrow table`.  I tried to get sum of quantity_borrow by using `borrow_qty = Borrow.query.filter_by(book_id=self.book_name.data).all()
 total = sum(borrow_qty.quantity_borrow)` but i received error **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'quantity_borrow'** How can i get the sum of quantity_borrow from borrow table where book_id = self.book_name.data

Comment: You can implement the quantity of borrowed books just like the book clsss itself. By querying borrowed books and then calculating the available book quantity depending on the book_id

Comment: I'm not sure how I can do it. Could you please provide me with some example. I tried couple of solutions but every time  do that i receive **TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable** or **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'quantity_borrow'**

Comment: You should iterate the all result and sum the quantities borrowed then: `sum(i.quantity_borrow for i in borrow_qty)`. Your query with .all() returns a list. You can loop over that list and then reach the quantity borrowed for each item in that list

Comment: I'm updating the answer to count borrowed quantities too